# Yahoo access using Tor

Tags: configuration, email

In the past week, I have not been able to access my Yahoo Mail account using Tor. Has something changed recently? I tried using the Yahoo Mail and Yahoo! rules but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did it "not work"? Can you give some details on what error you got?

Comment: via the web interface or via pop or imap?

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo Mail is actively disabling Tor users e-mail account. At first you might think Yahoo Mail is a good choice for Tor, since the signup always works flawlessly (unlike other e-mail providers), but after using you account a few times they block it.

That is my repeated experience.

See [here for a list of alternatives](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/where-i-can-get-largest-list-of-tor-friendly-email-services).