# Where I can get largest list of Tor-friendly email services?

Tags: email

There was a TorMail: `Tor Mail is a free anonymous email service provider` http://tormail.org

After FBI intel led to a raid in Ireland it become down
http://jhiwjjlqpyawmpjx.onion

I can use

- http://aol.com - js required.
- http://hotmail.com - from time to time locks account. Now requires js.
- http://excite.com - js required.
- http://yandex.com - js required.

Where I can get a full list of Tor-friendly E-mail services?

I've browse [Open Directory Project: E-mail](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/E-mail/)
E.g. 5 E-mail services of Italy give me nothing, 100 tries of capthas - fail, local cell phone required, etc...

Comment: You can probably get around the JS requirement by using Thunderbird or something instead of their web interface

Comment: Do not forget these:
https://services.autistici.org/?_lang=en
They have a .onion domain to access their services as well.

Comment: Looks like SPAM defeated Free Speech.

Comment: Service recommendation questions tend to generate spammy answers, and don't contribute much valuable information to the community. Tentatively, they are offtopic. Please discuss in this meta question: http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/questions/238/questions-asking-for-service-recommendations If we decide that they are ontopic after more discussion, I'll be sure to reopen.

Comment: This question was asked (and answered) on the `Software Recommendations` Stack Exchange here: [Looking for a Tor email that *doesnt* require JS to run](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86628/looking-for-a-tor-email-that-doesnt-require-js-to-run)

Answer (score 3):

### Pond

[Pond](https://pond.imperialviolet.org/) is not an email provider, but a new protocol to send messages. It runs over Tor and uses OTR to encrypt all messages.

> So Pond is not email. Pond is forward secure, asynchronous messaging for the discerning. Pond messages are asynchronous, but are not a record; they expire automatically a week after they are received. Pond seeks to prevent leaking traffic information against everyone except a global passive attacker.

Comment: Why did you split your answer?

Comment: This should enable all to add details and to vote for a single solution.

Comment: You should better merge this into one answer, I'll accept it, and community will fill it by additions.

Comment: This question is about e-mail, but Pond is not e-mail, or is it?

Answer (score 3):

SigAint is an email provider located in the hidden services. 
http://sigaintevyh2rzvw.onion/

Answer (score 2):

### Posteo.de

[Posteo](https://posteo.de/) is a german mail provider. You can register via Tor anonymously. Posteo is free of ads and encrypts all internal communication. They want [1 € per month](https://posteo.de/site/leistungen#leistungenkonditionen) for their services. This can be paid in cash.

Answer (score 2):

## Mail2Tor

There is also this one (apparently Tor friendly and completely free). It works, but I have only used it occasionally.

http://mail2tor2zyjdctd.onion/

You will get an @mail2tor.com address.

Answer (score 2):

safe mail is israelian, it is like that mosad offer you email or NSA.

vfemail.net
urssmail.org
mailtor.net (mailtoralnhyol5v.onion)
bitmessage.ch

Comment: VFEmail.net has https://344c6kbnjnljjzlz.onion.

Answer (score 1):

### SO36.net

[mail36.net](https://so36.net/services/mail/) is a service run by some private people. In order to get an account they require you to write them a mail and describe shortly why you want to use the service. The services at so36 can by used via Tor.

Answer (score 1):

### Lelantos

[Lelantos](http://lelantoss7bcnwbv.onion/) is a Tor hidden service and allows you to register an own email address. At current prices they want 35 $ (0.04 Bitcoin) for a lifetime subscription.

Answer (score 1):

### URSSMail

[URSSMail](https://www.urssmail.org/) is another mail service which is based on a hidden service. The [URSSMail hidden service](http://f3ljvgyyujmnfhvi.onion/) is free of charge, but you can donate to the project using Bitcoin or other *coins (Litecoin, Dogecoin etc.).

Answer (score 1):

We created an email service, currently in beta, 100% free and open source, specifically Tor friendly.
Check out the features list: https://ruggedinbox.com/features.php