# tormail error message

Tags: onion-services, email

when trying to get to tormail, thru tormail.org, I keep getting the below error. please help. thanks

> 500 Internal Privoxy Error
>
> Privoxy encountered an error while processing your request:
>
> Could not load template file forwarding-failed or one of its included components.
>
> Please contact your proxy administrator.
>
> If you are the proxy administrator, please put the required file(s)in the (confdir)/templates directory. The location of the (confdir) directory is specified in the main Privoxy config file. (It's typically the Privoxy install directory, or /etc/privoxy/).

Answer (score 1):

A while ago the FBI [raided Freedom Hosting](https://openwatch.net/i/200/anonymous-web-host-freedom-hosting-owner-arrested). They took several hidden services as well as TorMail down. So you can reach http://tormail.org/, but not their hidden service anymore.

There is a question which wants to find out [other Tor-friendly email services](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1207/88). Maybe this can help you.